# Searching for text

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, grep

I'm trying to write a shell script that searches for text within a file and prints out the text and associated information to a separate file.

From this file containing list of gene IDs:

```
DDIT3   ENSG00000175197
DNMT1   ENSG00000129757
DYRK1B  ENSG00000105204
```

I want to search for these gene IDs (ENSG*), their RPKM1 and RPKM2 values in a gtf file:

```
chr16   gencodeV7       gene    88772891        88781784        0.126744        +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000174177.7"; transcript_ids "ENST00000453996.1,ENST00000312060.4,ENST00000378384.3,"; RPKM1 "1.40735"; RPKM2 "1.61345"; iIDR "0.003";
chr11   gencodeV7       gene    55850277        55851215        0.000000        +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000225538.1"; transcript_ids "ENST00000425977.1,"; RPKM1 "0"; RPKM2 "0"; iIDR "NA";
```

and print/ write it to a separate output file

```
Gene_ID         RPKM1   RPKM2
ENSG00000108270 7.81399 8.149
ENSG00000101126 12.0082 8.55263
```

I've done it on the command line using for each ID using:

```
grep -w "ENSGno" rnaseq.gtf| awk '{print $10,$13,$14,$15,$16}' > output.file
```

but when it comes to writing the shell script, I've tried various combinations of for, while, read, do and changing the variables but without success. Any ideas would be great!

Comment: How do you get those RPKM[12] values from the sample data?

Comment: The RPKM are a measure of mRNA abundance in the sample; the technique is RNAseq. RPKM is defined as reads per kilobase per million read. Hope this helps? Thanks Harriet

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
while read line
do
  var=$(echo $line | awk '{print $2}')
  grep -w "$var" rnaseq.gtf| awk '{print $10,$13,$14,$15,$16}' >> output.file
done < geneIDs.file
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried it and I get the gene ID and it's corresponding RPKM1&2 values but it prints out all of the gene IDS from the target rnaseq.gtf file. I'm not sure how to search for the terms found in the source geneID.csv file against the same target rnaseq.gtf file over and over again and print just the matched geneID and RPKM1&2 values in to a separate output file. Thanks Harriet

Comment: Mmmm I don't really get the problem. Can you update your post with exact input and exact output needed? I just wrapped your `grep` to be used in a `while read file`, assuming `grep` was doing the job properly.